# in-app purchases from app store for enterprise applications

Tags: enterprise, subscription, in-app-purchase

I'm building an ipad app that will be used by companies.  This app will have a monthly subscription model for users (the app is not a publication, it's an productivity app).  Apple's terms and conditions states that I must use iAP to manage the subscriptions, and cannot redirect users to a website.  My question is:

Individual customers will go to the app store and download the app, but it'll be the company that pays for their subscription, not each individual user.  How can I make this happen with the least amount of burden for the user (e.g., I'm trying to avoid having the user pay, and making the company reimburse them).

Any thoughts of tips appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a potentially complicated licensing set-up where only [contacting Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/) would help to sort out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the App Store Guidelines state:

> 11.1 - Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

The Guidelines also say:

> 11.14 - Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage)
>   that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as
>   there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the
>   approved content.

It appears that companies like Evernote and Dropbox use this. There is no link to upgrade or buy an account in either of their apps that is not IAP. But you can also pay to upgrade on the site, not through the app.

So you can offer the subscription both in the App via IAP and via the website. A company could pay for an account on the website and give that login to their employees and you wouldn't run afoul of the App Store Guidelines.

mini disclaimer: As always, the App Store Guidelines change so read them directly yourself. Also, the final say in any of this is Apple, so see if you can contact them before you invest a lot of time and or money in building the app.